# Образование адресов

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, решил на сайте написать блоговый раздел, всё могу кроме одного: хочу адрес блога в таком формате: `site/some_blog`, а могу только `site/blogs.php?id=some_blog` :)

Вопрос следующий: как создавать краткие адреса?? неужели папки создавать?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам поможет [mod_rewrite](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=ru&newwindow=1&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=mod_rewrite&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=f118e6d2512dfaeb&ix=sea&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1821&bih=857)
[Весьма неплохая статья о нем на русском с картинками](http://www.egoroff.spb.ru/portfolio/apache/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Спасибо, частично понимаю, а иных способов нет?

Comment: Создать папку. URL станет длиннее всего на один символ  site/some_blog/

Comment: А вообще же простым людям все равно, что в адресе- они придут на сайт или по ссылке, или из поисковика, а ради тех кому не все равно в рамках домашней странички нет смысла заморачиваться.

Comment: блоги будут для муз. групп, адреса которых они будут где-нибудь выкладывать(пока мои мечты конечно:)), и тогда адрес будет иметь роль) т.е. через $_server['request_uri'] просто определять конкретный блог?

Answer (score 2):

То о чем вы говорите, называется [ЧПУ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3_%28%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%29) (Человекопонятный УРЛ). Тут вам надо почитать про [mod_rewrite](http://www.seoblog.com.ua/2008/11/04/kratkoe-rukovodstvo-po-htaccess-and-mod_rewrite/).

Comment: Человекопонятный УРЛ - спасибо, огромная помощь в плане: "как гуглить" :)